# jsoup css selector :not

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, jsoup

I want to know if jsoup support this css selector:

```
$('select[name=bankType] option:not([value=])')
```

It works in **jQuery 1.8**, but it does not work not work with **jsoup 1.7.2**. I wan to know if there's any equivalent syntax to perform this function.

Comment: I hope the next time you will search a little bit more =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:not(selector)` *elements that do not match the selector.*

Check out the documentation about [jsoup cssSelector](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

Example : `div:not(.logo)` *finds all divs that do not have the "logo" class.*